# CDP spark cluster mode read hive table, Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdp

my env

cdp verison: 7.4.4

spark version:2.4.7.7.1.7.0-551

my java code is this

my submit cmd:

```
./spark-submit --class com.abc.bdms.sparksql.SparkSQLDriver --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 2G  --num-executors 4  --keytab /home/bdms/flow.keytab --principal aa_qa/dev@HADOOP.COM  /home/easyops/spark-sql-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "select * from ods_employee_info_upload_bby2;"
```

it has exception:

```
diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication
```

how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

my code

```
package com.abc.bdms.sparksql;

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class SparkSQLDriver {

    private static String removeSemicolon(String origin) {
        if (origin == null || origin.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        String ret = origin.trim();
        if (ret.endsWith(";") && !ret.endsWith("\\;")) {
            return ret.substring(0, ret.length() - 1);
        } else {
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
        String version = spark.version();

        System.out.println("spark version:" + version);
        System.out.println("exec sqls");
        for (String s : args) {

            String sql = removeSemicolon(s);
            System.out.println("exec sql: " + sql);
            spark.sparkContext().setJobDescription(sql);
            spark.sql(sql).show();
            spark.sparkContext().setJobDescription(null);
        }

        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

and log

```
22/10/24 20:40:47 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDelegationToken(FSNamesystem.java:5913)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getDelegationToken(NameNodeRpcServer.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:1199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:917)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2894)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:1128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:362)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDelegationToken(DFSClient.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getDelegationToken(DistributedFileSystem.java:1976)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.DelegationTokenIssuer.collectDelegationTokens(DelegationTokenIssuer.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.DelegationTokenIssuer.addDelegationTokens(DelegationTokenIssuer.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
    at com.netease.bdms.sparksql.SparkSQLDriver.main(SparkSQLDriver.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:665)

     ApplicationMaster host: vnode5.local
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 43887
     queue: default
     start time: 1666615157796
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://vnode4.local:8088/proxy/application_1666603720817_0016/
     user: mammut_qa
22/10/24 20:40:47 ERROR yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDelegationToken(FSNamesystem.java:5913)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getDelegationToken(NameNodeRpcServer.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:1199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:917)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2894)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:1128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:362)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDelegationToken(DFSClient.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getDelegationToken(DistributedFileSystem.java:1976)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.DelegationTokenIssuer.collectDelegationTokens(DelegationTokenIssuer.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.DelegationTokenIssuer.addDelegationTokens(DelegationTokenIssuer.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
    at com.netease.bdms.sparksql.SparkSQLDriver.main(SparkSQLDriver.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:665)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1666603720817_0016 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1208)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1662)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:847)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:922)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:931)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
22/10/24 20:40:47 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/10/24 20:40:47 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bbdf619f-0437-4bb1-b573-5557c4f4dde4
22/10/24 20:40:47 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-9e4fee64-411a-4985-9958-ed674ce65d7c
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running in a cluster that is using kerberos?
If you run the `klist` comand, do you have any output?

Comment: This is not an answer this part of original question, @hehe move this code and log into the original question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).